# IIS Content-Disposition file name encoded twice

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewrite-module, content-disposition, arr

When downloading a file, the Content-Disposition is encoded twice. This leads to unreadable file names for non-ascii characters.

This double encoding happens only when the request is being processed by the IIS rewrite module 2.0 and routed to a server farm. In this situation, when the code offers the file as a download, the response header, Content-Disposition, is double encoded. The browser decodes this once, which leaves with an encoded file name where non-ascii characters are unreadable.

In a situation where the same request is being processed without IIS rewrite module and ARR. The response header, Content-Disposition is encoded, but only once. In this case the browser decodes the filename and non-ascii characters are readable.

I've been looking into this for days now. I've only found 1 other question like this, but without an awnser.

For reference, here is the code used for the download file. (ASP.NET application)
In this code, report represents an entityframework object, and the filename is an unencoded string. We don't encode the filename. So i'm not even sure what is responsible for the first encoding.

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=" + report.FileName);
response.TransmitFile(filePath);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Here are 2 images to display the issue:

Example download request header with IIS rewrite and ARR:
[image: Example download request header with IIS rewrite and ARR]

Example download request header without IIS rewrite and ARR
[image: Example download request header without IIS rewrite and ARR]

Any ideas on a solution? (Not using rewrite/arr/server farm is not an option)

EDIT:

Image of content-disposition found in failed tracelog.
It does look like ASP.NET automatically URL encodes the filename.
Makes it even more confusing.
[Content-disposition-failed-trace-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve6ce.png)

Additionally the inbound rewrite rule, that redirects traffic to a webfarm. (This webfarm is hosted in the same IIS on the same server)
[Inbound-rewrite-rule-web-farm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jPEc.png)

Comment: What's your rewrite rule? I think you can use failed request tracing to trace request. Then check which step encode file name in url rewrite module.

Comment: Hi @BruceZhang, i've made an edit with results of the request tracing and added the rewrite rule. Any ideas?